# Mac OSX Console doesn't show Sandbox violations

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'm about to publish an update to my app on the Mac AppStore and wanted to check for sandbox violations. Compiled my app with entitlements and code-signed it... it's running, Activity Monitor confirms it is using a sandboxed enviroment.

My problem is Console is not showing any line coming from sandboxd. Even if I deliberately simulate a violation: like disabling user-selected file read/write access and trying to open a file, the OpenPanel never shows up (I imagine sandbox blocks it) but Console never shows a line reporting it. The only line I get if I search the Console for "sandboxd" is one telling something about an unknown POSIXSpawnInterface.

My doubts/questions are:

1) (removed!)

2) If my app is able to do whatever I need it to do (I open MIDI inputs so I had to include a temporary exception entitlement for mach-global access) does it mean that I'm ok with sandboxing it even if console is not reporting any violations?!

3) My app search for a file (an app bundle) by querying the system for the path via its application id (the one which reads like com.company.appname) then I use NSBundle to retrieve just the version of it. Do these operations need a temporary exception entitlement for read-only file access to the Application folder (actually I don't know the exact path because it depends on where the user installed the app)?

Thank you in advance for the suggestions you'll be able to provide.
Regards, Peter.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running on?

Comment: You really shouldn't cram multiple questions into one question. For 1), it's possible you're just doing the wrong tests. If you try to open a file with user-selected file read/write access disabled, I think it doesn't even get far enough for sandboxd to block it. Instead, try just opening some file outside of the sandbox with open/fopen/-dataWithContentsOfURL:/whatever and see if that does it.

Comment: For 2), if your app isn't violating anything, of course you won't see any violations (although there are some bugs in sandboxd and powerboxd that mean that isn't always true…). So if you see no violations, yes, it's perfectly possible that you're OK with sandboxing.

Comment: For 3), you're not supposed to be able to do this. Of course a temporary exception entitlement for read-only on / will work, but nothing short of that. The right answer is to ask the user to locate the file you want to open via an NSOpenPanel. Yes, even if you know where the file is, you have to ask the user. You can make the NSOpenPanel look like a "confirmation dialog" (specify an initial URL, and add a delegate that doesn't accept anything else). And if they're on 10.7.3+, you can persist that access after first run in an app-scoped bookmark. But you do have to ask.

Comment: @Dov: I tried that on 10.7.4 but I'm testing the app both on 10.8 and good old 10.6.8.

Comment: @Peter: 10.6.8 has no sandbox, so you won't see anything in the logs, and nothing will be denied. 10.7.4 and 10.8 should be pretty similar. But meanwhile, can you tell us which of the questions you're actually asking, and exactly what information you're missing?

Comment: I answered question 1 myself, sandboxd was indeed running on my machine. All of my questions above originated from my "violation detection" session which ended with no violation being reported on Console while, from what I read, I was actually violating some of the entitlements... @abarnert is probably right, my test about question 2) were wrong but still, I found something interesting.

Comment: I have two partitions on my development station (one running 10.7.4, the second running 10.8) when I launched the app on 10.8 it asked the system for the path of the app (querying it by its identifier as explained above), the app was not installed on the second partiton but apparently Mountain Lion was able to find the bundle with that ID even if it was on the other partiton (which is a different drive from the OS point of view)... well, in this case the access to the bundle to read the version has been denied and a violation reported in Console!

Comment: This is weird since I never had a temporary file access entitlement in my entitlements file (not for /Applications, not even for the whole /) but when the app is on the same logic drive (that is, when I run the same test after installing the app with that ID even on 10.8) accces is being granted with no violations reported.